# Removing # from column value returned using regexp_substr

Tags: mysql

In my following sql query, I am getting columns with #.

with texttab as

```
 (
   SELECT 
   ROOT_CAUSE as text
   from cust_bug_data where ROOT_CAUSE is not NULL
 )
   SELECT regexp_substr(text,'\#[a-z0-9_]+',1,level,'i') as tag
   FROM texttab
   CONNECT BY regexp_substr(text,'\#[a-z0-9_]+',1,level,'i') IS NOT 
   NULL
```

Following output I am getting with above query.

#test

#timing
 #test
 #timing
 #code

I want my query to return values without #, like as follows:
    test

```
timing
test
timing
code
```

Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: You need to format your question better and provide more test cases/outcomes: what if the '#' is in the middle or the end of the string? Do you just to remove the '#' or do you want the text after the '#'? Is using regexp_substr() a constraint on the implementation or do you just want a means of achieving the resuly using MySQL?

Comment: My cust_bug_data table column ROOT_CAUSE has following content:

ROOT_CAUSE(column)
--------------------------------
This is a #test issue.
#timing
this is #test issue.
#timing
#code

Comment: You also need a lot more about problem analysis before trying to design an application to support the process.

Answer (score 0):

Following query gave above mentioned result to me:

select replace(tag,'#','') as tag from(
with texttab as
(
SELECT 
  ROOT_CAUSE as text
from cust_bug_data where ROOT_CAUSE is not NULL
)
SELECT regexp_substr(text,'#[a-z0-9_]+',1,level,'i') as tag
FROM texttab
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(text,'#[a-z0-9_]+',1,level,'i') IS NOT NULL) t